# Are the security implications of installing NodeJS in the public HTML folder?

Tags: node.js

I'm running NodeJS for my server-side javascripting, but serving my pages with Apache.

My pages currently reference Socket.IO locally, in that they load the `node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js` from the `/var/www/html`

The NodeJS index.js file also resides in `/var/www/html` which has become a problem for me.

Can I move my NodeJS index.js file to `var/www` so it is no longer publicly accessible, without needing to move `node_modules` from `var/www/html` which Socket.IO is relying on to be publicly accessible?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but root directory of your web server should not be publicly visible, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When using Node.js to serve the Webpage:**

Your servers root directory is typically not publicly visible. Requests to your server get handled by the routes you set up in the index.js file. By default, no files are accessible. However, if you need a public folder (e.g. for the favicon file or an index.html file), I would recommend creating a subfolder in your root directory and use for example [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to make it available.

**When not using Node.js to serve the Webpage:**

If you need Node.js for client-side logic, you should just use normal javascript (for example [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) in the case of WebSockets). Node.js is a serverside application where you run javascript on the server. So on the client-side, there is no need for Node.js. If you need certain npm packages, SubStack on GitHub has a module called [node-browserify](http://browserify.org/). It will compress and bundle your modules and deliver it as a single js file, but you use it just like Node.js.

If you need Node.js for server-side logic, then there is no need to make it publicly available and you should change your current server configuration to not make it accessible from the browser.

Comment: Sorry, should have said, I'm not using NodeJS to serve my webpages, just for Websockets. My server has a /html folder, and my NodeJS install (and index.js) are in a subfolder to that.  Navigation is blocked, but manually typing in the path to the index.js file will render it in the browser. I'm thinking it should sit somewhere else other than /html?

Comment: I hope I added an answer regarding your use case. If I still didn't get what you are trying to do, please explain your project in more detail.

Comment: Hi Valentin, I have re-worded my question. I started to look in to the process and decided I needed more advice to be able to continue. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, TM